# NativeScript Image with path won't load but url works fine

Tags: angular, nativescript

My NativeScript Image is not showing when I use a a path to a file. My code currently looks like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Image src="~/assets/logo"></Image>
    <Image src="https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/NativeScript_logo.png"></Image>
</StackLayout>
```

The lower Image using a url is showing up but the one above isn't.

I also tried these:

```
    <Image src="/assets/logo.png"></Image>
    <Image src="../assets/logo.png"></Image>
    <Image src="../../assets/logo.png"></Image>
```

And other options but nothing works.

I have a folder `assets` inside my `app` folder and inside I have a `logo.png` picture, which is the picture from the url above.

Also I don't get any console message, that it can't find my file.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you give a try for `~/app/assets/logo.png`?

Comment: try `<Image src="./assets/logo.png"></Image>` or `<image src="./assets/logo.png"></image>`. Notice that the path is `./`

Comment: relative path depends on the path your app is running under, is it `/app`? `/dist`? find out and use it

Comment: @Manoj thanks it works with `~/app/assets`. Even though in the docs they just use `~/assets`.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi My component is not in the same folder as the assets. Its in `app/pages/mypage`, while assets is in `app/assets`. So `../../` should work as far as I know but it isn't `./` isn't working either.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your structure looks like this:

`app/
  assets/
    logo.png
  components/
    ...
  app.component.ts
  ...`

I'd recommend trying:
`<Image src="~/assets/logo.png"></Image>`

`~/` means you're looking in home directory of your project.

Check if `app` is actually your home directory. It might be `src` above `app`. Then you'd need to go for `~/app/asset/...`

Comment: Yes my structure looks like this. I tried that and it still not working. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: I see in your comments, that you had to go with ```~/app/assets```. It seemts that your home directory is ```src```, not ```app```.
Glad that you've found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

it should contain extension name

```
 <Image src="~/assets/logo.png"></Image>
```